# Why is this merge sort implementation not working properly?

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort

The following is my merge sort implementation, what it does is it takes an array of pairs of integers and sorts them according  to second element in the pair (ties are broken by first element in pair and all elements are distinct)

```
void mer(vector<pair<int, int>> a, int l, int m, int r, vector<pair<int, int>> res) {
    int i = l;
    int j = m;
    int k = l;
    while (i < m && j < r) {
        if (a[i].second < a[j].second) {
            res[k] = a[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        } else
        if (a[i].second > a[j].second) {
            res[k] = a[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        } else {
            if (a[i].first > a[j].first) {
                res[k] = a[j];
                k++;
                j++;
            } else {
                res[k] = a[i];
                i++;
                k++;
            }
        }
    }
    while (i < m) {
        res[k] = a[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while (j < r) {
        res[k] = a[j];
        k++;
        j++;
    }
    for (int i = l; i < r; i++) {
        a[i] = res[i];
    }
}
    
void solve(vector<pair<int, int>> a, int l, int r, vector<pair<int, int>> res) {
    if (l < r) {
        int m = (l + r) / 2;
        solve(a, l, m, res);
        solve(a, m + 1, r, res);
        mer(a, l, m, r, res);
    }
}
```

But when I run my code with `main`:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    map<int, int> a;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int u;
        cin >> u;
        a[u]++;
    }
    vector<pair<int, int>> b;
    for (auto i : a) {
        b.push_back(i);
    }
    vector<pair<int, int>> res(b.size());
    solve(b, 0, b.size(), res);
}
```

Consider my input to be:

```
10
1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 3 3
it outputs 
1 6
2 2
3 2
```

That is what ever the input is output is same .
I have spent a lot of time looking for the problem. I am not able to fix it.

Comment: For a start, please format your code consistently. Being able to read it, to recognize its structure is important for understanding it, which in turn help finding and fixing mistakes. Further, reduce your code to a [mcve]. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the `vector` objects should be passed by reference.
- `res` is not the destination of the `solve()` function, but rather an auxiliary vector to act as temporary storage for `mer`. Calling it `tmp` would be less confusing.
- the `r` index in `solve()` is excluded, so the test fo a slice with less than 2 elements and the recursive calls should be:

  ```
  void mer(vector<pair<int, int>>& a, int l, int m, int r, vector<pair<int, int>>& res) {
      int i = l;
      int j = m;
      int k = l;
      while (i < m && j < r) {
          if (a[i].second < a[j].second) {
              res[k] = a[i];
              i++;
              k++;
          } else
          if (a[i].second > a[j].second) {
              res[k] = a[j];
              j++;
              k++;
          } else {
              if (a[i].first > a[j].first) {
                  res[k] = a[j];
                  k++;
                  j++;
              } else {
                  res[k] = a[i];
                  i++;
                  k++;
              }
          }
      }
      while (i < m) {
          res[k] = a[i];
          k++;
          i++;
      }
      while (j < r) {
          res[k] = a[j];
          k++;
          j++;
      }
      for (int i = l; i < r; i++) {
          a[i] = res[i];
      }
  }

  void solve(vector<pair<int, int>>& a, int l, int r, vector<pair<int, int>>& tmp) {
      if (r - l >= 2) {
          int m = (l + r) / 2;
          solve(a, l, m, tmp);
          solve(a, m, r, tmp);
          mer(a, l, m, r, tmp);
      }
  }
  ```
- in the `main()` function, you do not store the input values into the vector of pairs and you should also print the sorted pairs:

  ```
  int main() {
      int n;
      cin >> n;

      vector<pair<int, int>> a(n);

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          a[i].first = i + 1;
          cin >> a[i].second;
      }
      vector<pair<int, int>> tmp(n);
      solve(a, 0, n, tmp);
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          printf("%d %d\n", a[i].first, a[i].second);
      }
      return 0
  }
  ```